# How to display dynamic page description in a shared angularJS page (via google +1 for instance)

Tags: facebook, angularjs, seo, google-plus, meta

I am trying enable the metas in our app for google+ and facebook +1's and I get either nothing, the url of the page, or {{pageDesc}} in the post. Right now I am using a directive that dynamically sets the meta description:

HTML:

```
<meta meta-description>
```

DIRECTIVE:

```
app.directive('metaDescription', [ 'metaData', function(metaData){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<meta name="description" content="{{description}}">',
    link: function(scope,element){
      scope.metaData = metaData;
      scope.description = scope.metaData.pageDesc;

    }
  };
}]);
```

When doing this, the google api does not recognize the title and description and just sets the url of the current page and the url of the site as title/description.

I was poking around with prerender.io but I had to disable it because it made the +1 plugin crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set those values in the HTML before you render the document. The Facebook/Google/etc bots that crawl the pages don't usually execute JavaScript.

Comment: Ok one question though, when I use the share features, is that crawling bots looking at my site? In that case if I block crawling in robots.txt, they won't catch the meta on the page? I am trying to use prerender.io to make our app more seo friendly but right now we are blocking the bots, so it's a bit hard to test things out.

Comment: Using G+ sharing causes a Google server to fetch and parse the page. I don't believe that fetch respects robots.txt as it's not crawling your site but rather requesting a specific page. (I could be wrong about that). You should test with the [Google data testing tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test your markup.

Comment: If you're using prerender.io, the meta tags will be rendered into the page and returned to the crawler as static HTML.